# Making dropdown appear on top of map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm trying to create a map with drop down in it I want the drop down to appear on the map like map shows in background and dropdown on top of it. Right now it is looking
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKeB.png)

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#map {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px;">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Select Country</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>

</div>
```

and here is the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to wrap both the components in a container, giving the container the `position: relative` attribute, then position the dropdown using `position: absolute` with the `top` and `left` values you require.

Here is an example of how you would achieve it:

```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background: white; /* TODO: Remove this temporary styling */
    display: inline-block;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  #map {
    background: black; /* TODO: Remove this temporary styling */
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/hiuuHaf.png'); /* TODO: Remove this temporary styling */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* TODO: Remove this temporary styling */
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div
  class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"
  style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Select Country</span>
      <div class="dropdown-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply remove the CSS where I have commented `/* TODO: Remove this temporary styling */` which is purely for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Try something like this,

```html
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
#map {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `position: relative;` in the parent and then `position: absolute;` on the dropdown.

Something like this

```css
#container {
position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

#map {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10rem;
    /*position:absolute;
    display: block;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px;"> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Select Country</span>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          
        </div>
      </div>
        <div id="map">This is the map</div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Replace the `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`'s display property to inline

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline;
}

#map {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px;">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Select Country</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Case 2: Put the select-menu inside the `map` div.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline;
}

#map {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px;">
  
  <div id="map">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Select Country</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Case 3: You can also put `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child. Then you can play around with the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties.[Read on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
But again, to achieve this you must put the `select-menu (the children)` inside the `map (parent)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

replaced `dropdown-content:absoulte`and pushing 100% from top `top:100%`.
keeping the `height:0` and adding the `height:100px` and `padding on hover`.
because in case you want animation you woulnt be able to do it `display:none`
also added a `transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;`

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  height:100px;
  
}

#map {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px;">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Select Country</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>

</div>
```